# rsync --exclude not excluding specific files

Tags: linux, rsync

I am currently running an rsync command to backup my specific folder.

Here is the command:

```
rsync -rtzv -e --exclude "generator/" --exclude "workspace/gallery/server/lib/personas_constants.php"  /home/brandon/workspace/gallery /home/brandon/workspace/gallery2
```

The issue I am having is the --exclude is not excluding the specific files.  It is the relative path to the files from where I am running the rsync command.  The exclude does however work for the "generator/" directory.

Can someone shine some light on this for me?

Comment: As a note for anyone Googling this without their glasses. --exclude has two dashes in front.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turned out that it is the relative path from the folders that are being rsync'd with one another.  Not from where you are running the rsync command.

```
--exclude "generator/" --exclude "server/lib/personas_constants.php" --exclude "server/lib/connect.php"
```

Fixed my issues.

Comment: THANK YOU! Been searching for this

Answer (score 2):

The `--exclude` argument takes a pattern, and file names that match that pattern are excluded - not the specific path to a file.

If you don't have any other files called `personas_constants.php`, then `--exclude personas_constants.php` should do the trick - otherwise you'll have to do something fiddly including `--exclude-from` and moving some files around.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've had better luck using an exclude file. It was quite some time ago but it might be worth a shot.