# Is there a way to move files from one set of directories to another set of corresponding directories

Tags: bash

I take delivery of files from multiple places as part of a publishing aggregation service. I need a way to move files that have been delivered to me from one location to another without losing the directory listings for sorting purposes.

Example:

```
Filepath of delivery: Server/Vendor/To_Company/Customer_Name/**
Filepath of processing: ~/Desktop/MM-DD-YYYY/Returned_Files/Customer_Name/**
```

I know I can move all of the directories by doing something such as:

```
find Server/Vendor/To_Company/* -exec mv -n ~/Desktop/MM-DD-YYYY/Returned_Files \;
```

but using that I can only run the script one time per day and there are times when I might need to run it multiple times.

It seems like ideally I should be able to create a copycat directory in my daily processing folder and then move the files from one to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use rsync command with --remove-source-files option. you can run it as many times as needed.

```
#for trial run, without making any actual transfer.
rsync --dry-run -rv --remove-source-files Server/Vendor/To_Company/ ~/Desktop/MM-DD-YYYY/Returned_Files/

#command
rsync -rv --remove-source-files Server/Vendor/To_Company/ ~/Desktop/MM-DD-YYYY/Returned_Files/
```

reference:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-rsync-delete-file-after-transfer/

Comment: Thanks, @neon! One more question: can I exclude a directory using that? I was reading through the massive rsync man page and didn't see that I could?

Comment: +1 for supplying `--dry-run`, it's always good to test first!

Comment: you can use --exclude "PATTERN" option.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720234/rsync-exclude-not-excluding-specific-files

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rsync` to do this for you:

```
rsync -a --remove-source-files /Server/Vendor/To_Company/Customer_Name ~/Desktop/$(date +"%y-%m-%d")/Returned_files/
```

Add `-n` to do a dry run to make sure it does what you want.

From the manual page:

```
   --remove-source-files
          This  tells  rsync  to  remove  from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the
          transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

          Note that you should only use this option on source files that are quiescent.  If you are  using  this  to  move
          files that show up in a particular directory over to another host, make sure that the finished files get renamed
          into the source directory, not directly written into it, so that rsync can’t possibly transfer a  file  that  is
          not  yet  fully written.  If you can’t first write the files into a different directory, you should use a naming
          idiom that lets rsync avoid transferring files that are not yet finished (e.g. name the file "foo.new"  when  it
          is  written,  rename it to "foo" when it is done, and then use the option --exclude='*.new' for the rsync trans‐
          fer).
```